# After doing SET NEW_BROKER, getting "target service name could not be found"

Tags: service-broker

I made a mistake.  After realizing that SB was causing crashes (and had been for a while), I had it patched.  Now, I had millions of messages backed up in a queue, it was trying to catch up on messages from other machines, and disk space was running out.  Even with 4 readers it was falling behind.

So I did the only thing I could think of at the time.  Which was stupid of me.

```
ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Now, I'm trying to clean up from that mistake.  The first thing I tried to do is alter the ROUTEs on the sending servers so they matched.  That doesn't seem to be working - now the sys.transmission_queue on the senders says **"Target service name could not be found"**.  And I'm stumped on that - I see the service on the receiver, and I don't believe I changed anything with it.  I'm scripting out the CREATE ROUTE from the box via SSMS, then changing the broker instance with the results of service_broker_guid from sys.databases for the receiving database.

Looking at a profiler trace with broker, I'm seeing (on the receiving server) these messages:

```
Could not forward the message because forwarding is disabled in this SQL Server instance.

The message could not be delivered because it could not be classified. 
Enable broker message classification trace to see the reason for the failure.
```

Next up is doing endpoint cleanup on the senders, pulling the conversation_handle from sys.transmission_queue and using that to end it.

Update: okay, so I've cleaned out msdb.sys.transmission_queue, but I still have a 15gb MSDB, and it's got to be service broker (no tables using more than a few MB that I can see).  Considering doing the NEW_BROKER there as well, since I've turned everything off.  But that still seems like A Bad Idea.

The receiver is a R2 box, just patched to SP3.

At this point, I'm at a loss.  Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue where service broker suddenly and inexplicably stops delivering messages, they just accumulate in `sys.transmission_queue` and a profiler trace shows the error message `Could not forward the message because forwarding is disabled in this SQL Server instance.`

Executing this command fixed it:

```
alter endpoint ServiceBrokerEndpoint for service_broker (message_forwarding=enabled)
```

..which is odd since we never disabled message forwarding and never had to explicitly enable it before.